# Mobile changePage Url adding root directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Everytime I click to load the video in the new page, the url parameters are getting the base then repeating themselves.
So it goes from `/screen/mobile/videos.asp` to `/screen/mobile/videos.asp#/screen/mobile/videoplayers.asp?id=b7c5z654vz_ak0`

I've played around with it so much, but it seems no matter what I do it always resorts to the above, even when using absolute urls.

```
$(".videolink").unbind("click").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr("href");
            $.mobile.changePage("videoplayer.asp?id="+data);
            console.log('changing to videplayer.asp');
    });
```

Need to find a work around to it as the urls are not friendly at all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying an absolute URL? For example,

```
 $.mobile.changePage("/videoplayer.asp?id="+data);
```

Whenever JQM loads pages with AJAX it will do that - since it only appends the new div to the current DOM (it's not actually reloading the full page).

If you want to disable this AJAX loading (and actually load a fresh page into the browser), you need to look into [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) for example the AjaxEnabled property for setting this globally.

Hope this helps...